# QGIS Export Color mapped GeoTIFF to GeoTiFF

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

I've loaded a GeoTiff in QGIS (Single Band), and applied a Color Mapping.  I can view it in the map canvas, but I would like to export the *entire* mapped GeoTiff as an appropriate 3 Band GeoTiff (i.e to R,G,B values 0-255).

I know that you can export the current view -- but this is too low-resolution, and I would like to retain the current resolution.

Is there a hook in the Python QGIS module that might enable?

Answer (score 4):

Raster -> Conversion -> PCT to RGB.

Alternatively, right-click on the colour rendered image and go "Save As". Tick the "Rendered image" radio button.

N.

Comment: Thanks -- my data in RasterBand1 is not scaled (i.e. values greater than 256), so I get this error on Raster -> Conversion -> PCT to RGB:  

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pct2rgb.py", line 167, in 
dst_data = Numeric.take(band_lookup,src_data)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_9597b1f_20120920-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 104, in take
return take(indices, axis, out, mode)
IndexError: index 80000 is out of bounds for size 256

When using QGIS Colormap - how does it render the image?

Comment: Oh, how annoying. Have you tried the second method above? I'm using QGIS Master (1.9) here, not sure if this option is available in 1.8. I think you'll get RGB if you use the "Save as" method. N.